Rotating QGraphicsLineItems around a circle and not a point
So, I have a scene with two graphics circles, and a custom line item. I created two line items, where a boolean “foo” is passed in to determine how to separate the lines, as I want the circles connected via two lines like ||.
When I move the destination circle around the source, I want the lines to stay the same distance apart, but right now they move closer to each other as they approach y=x and flip on that line.
I have tried to implement a custom adjust function which gets called in the line item’s init:
def adjust(self, foo: bool):
   self.prepareGeometryChange()
   adjust = 4
   if not foo:
       adjust *= -1
   self.setLine(
      QtCore.QLineF(
           self.source.pos().x()+adjust,
           self.source.pos().y()+adjust,
           self.dest.pos().x()+adjust,
           self.dest.pos().y()+adjust,
       )
    )

What can I do to make them swivel around the circles instead of around a single point?

You're just translating the positions. Since you're dealing with circles and rotations, that means you need to use trigonometry functions. Alternatively, if you don't need to use the coordinates of the lines for some other computations, you can set the transformOriginPoint() to the center of the source, and then call setRotation() based on the angle between the two circles. Note that the call to prepareGeometryChange() is useless, as it's implicitly done by setLine().

I finally came back to this after months with an answer:
def adjust(self, foo: bool):
   self.prepareGeometryChange()

   delta = QtCore.QPointF(self.source.pos() - self.dest.pos())
   length = delta.manhattanLength()
   if length == 0.0:
      return self.setLine(
         QtCore.QLineF(
              self.source.pos(),
              self.dest.pos()
        )
     )

   direction = QtCore.QPointF(delta.x()/length, delta.y()/length)
   perpendicular = QtCore.QPointF(-direction.y(), direction.x())
   line_offset = 5

   sign = -1 if foo else 1

   x_adjust = (sign*perpendicular.x()) * (sign*line_offset)
   y_adjust = (sign*perpendicular.y()) * (sign*line_offset)

   self.setLine(
      QtCore.QLineF(
           self.source.pos().x()-x_adjust,
           self.source.pos().y()-y_adjust,
           self.dest.pos().x()-x_adjust,
           self.dest.pos().y()-y_adjust,
       )
    )

